# Django unique_together is not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class model_name(models.Model):
    pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field3 = models.ForeignKey(model3, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field4 = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together= (('field1', 'field2', 'field3'),)
        db_table = "table_name"
```

whenever I give data from Django admin app it says that it already exists.
it works fine there but when I give it manually it starts taking duplicates.

I have added the unique_together constraint but it still takes the duplicates for particular fields. what should I do to stop taking the already existing data?

I use mysql database

JSON:

```
 [
 {
   'field1': value1,
   'field2': value2,
   'field3': value3,
   'field4': some int

 },
 {
   'field1': value1,
   'field2': value2,
   'field3': value3,
   'field4': some int
 }
]
```

It pushes both into the databse

Any solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the inner parentheses.

Comment: What do you mean, 'when I give it manually'? Show the code you're using and what happens.

Comment: I mean when I give the data through JSON it takes the duplicates.

Comment: show the code and the json example, if you may

Comment: I expect the issue is that [model validation is not automatically run on save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run), but without seeing the actual code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: did you migrated ?

Comment: i have edited my post see,    yes, I have migrated them

Comment: How are you uploading the json?

Comment: Which django version you are using? `Makemigrations` and `migrate` should solve the issue

Comment: Try adding a comma to then end of the inner list:         unique_together= (('field1', 'field2', 'field3',),)

Comment: I am uploading JSON through API call